# How to add js file to module and insert it to module layout

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, orders, javascript, file

I have a module which add layout to admin create order like this:

> **app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/mymodule.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_order" name="mymodule_admin_order_create" template="mymodule/admin_order_create.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

I want to add my **`js`** file to the **`adminhtml_sales_order_create_index`**, but I don't know where to put the **`js`** file in my module directory and how to put it in the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
          <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs">
             <script>my_extension/adminhack.js</script></action>                        
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_order" name="mymodule_admin_order_create" template="mymodule/admin_order_create.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

Please replace above code in your layout file and add JS file in js/my_extension/adminhack.js.
Don't forget to clear cache.

Comment: i got console error saying js file not found

Comment: which URL you have added in layout file?

Comment: i've fixed it by moving to js folder

Comment: Okay Please correct/vote to my answer, if its helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>path/file_name.js</script></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="mymodule/adminhtml_order" name="mymodule_admin_order_create" template="mymodule/admin_order_create.phtml"></block>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: where to put the js file?

Comment: your `mymodule.xml` file